# JQuery - get all components values based on their positions

Tags: jquery

Lets say I have a page which has some components (dropdown, textbox etc) in rows and columns (3*5 matrix). The components gets added/removed dynamically by the user.

I want to get the values of all of the components based on their positions from top to end clockwise on submit. Effectively, I want the values in stack type data structure so that I know which values belongs to which component ? The order of the values is important.

Is it possible?

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I am doing something like this:- <code>$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#dataForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $inputs = $('#dataForm :input, div');</code> but it does not give the desited results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](http://api.jquery.com/each/)  I made it working!

```
$( "#dataForm :input, button" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( "Index="+index + "<> Text=" + $( this ).find(":selected").text() + "<> Value="+$( this ).val()+"<>Name="+$( this ).attr('name'));
    });
```